# i3 and rdesktop -- who gets the meta?

Tags: i3, rdesktop

I am using i3 desktop manager bound to my <kbd>Win</kbd> (or meta) key. Everything works great.

Sometimes, I like to `rdesktop` into my windows machines. Now, as long as the application window is focuses or fullscreen, my windows machines gets the <kbd>Win</kbd> keys. If I want send commands to i3, I'll have to exit full screen and focus on a different application. The transition is slightly awkward.

If I want to override the behavior I can invoke `rdesktop -k`. Now i3 listens to my windows keys. But, now windows can't hear my windows key. Now are windows shortcuts are disabled. Bummer.

Is there a way to get selectively send calls to windows/i3? Binding to <kbd>alt</kbd> doesn't solve the problem.